# Actionscript compiler MTASC and Events

Tags: actionscript

Please help, how to make netEvent work in a compiled flash, for instance I can't even make macromedia example to work:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

ns.onMetaData = function(infoObject:Object) {
    for (var propName:String in infoObject) {
        trace(propName + " = " + infoObject[propName]);
    }
};

ns.play("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/water.flv");
```

It must return metainfo, but seems like no event is called at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is right from Adobe docs:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.events.Event;

public class NetConnectionExample extends Sprite {
    private var videoURL:String = "Video.flv";
    private var connection:NetConnection;
    private var stream:NetStream;

    public function NetConnectionExample() {
        connection = new NetConnection();
        connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        connection.connect(null);
    }

    private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                connectStream();
                break;
            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                trace("Stream not found: " + videoURL);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function connectStream():void {
        stream = new NetStream(connection);
        stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        stream.client = new CustomClient();
        var video:Video = new Video();
        video.attachNetStream(stream);
        stream.play(videoURL);
        addChild(video);
    }
}
}

class CustomClient {
public function onMetaData(info:Object):void {
    trace("metadata: duration=" + info.duration + " width=" + info.width + " height=" + info.height + " framerate=" + info.framerate);
}
public function onCuePoint(info:Object):void {
    trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
}
}
```

Looks to me like you're missing quite a bit in the code that you posted and you won't get what you're looking for by missing required setup code.